# The contents in the java String pool

Tags: java, string

I have some questions about java String pool.

```
String s1 = "welcome" + " to" + " java";
String s2 = new String("HTML");
```

In the above situation,

My question is the intermediate Strings like "welcome to" added to the pool or not.
for example, in my thought, the current String pool has contents as below

```
"welcome"
" to"
"welcome to"
" java"
" to java"
"welcome to java"
```

please tell me if my thought is wrong.

Comment: 3 experts, 3 different answers, OK only two answers now.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler treats multiple constant strings concatenated as a single string. The above code is thus similar to

```
String s1 = "welcome to java";
String s2 = new String("HTML");
```

There are thus 2 strings stored in the pool by the above code: `"welcome to java"`, and `"HTML"`.

Comment: In my studying slides, they just says that only the strings with shorthand notation will be stored in the String pool. Then you 're saying that String object from the formal definition too stored in the String pool??

Comment: @user3473222 Yes you are right. Strings created with `new` keyword will be stored in Java Heap. Only Strings with shorthand notation will be stored in String Pool which is also in Java Heap.

Comment: @JB "HTML" will not be in the String Pool. Just to mention, i did not downvoted your answer.

Comment: @Sanjeev: the string literal "HTML" is used in this code, and it will thus be in the string pool, like all the other string literals.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to JB Nizet fo this.. :)

```
        String s1 = "Hellothere";// Hellothere added to SP
        String s2 = "Hello" + "there"; //Hellothere "already" present in SP
        System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true. And yes, I am intentionally comparing Strings using"=="
            String s3 = s1 + s2;
        String s4="HellothereHellothere";
        System.out.println(s3==s4);//False.. HellothereHelloThere NOT added to SP
```

Comment: Why does `System.out.println(s3==s4);` give `false` as output? Is it because `s3` is initialized with other variables instead of shortand notations?

Comment: @MehmetSedatGüngör - because s3 and s4 are different. S4 is on Stringpool whereas s3 is on heap.